# Build Once, Deploy Anywhere, with Maven, Jenkins, and Artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm in the latter stages of setting up a CI environment for my project. I'm using Maven, Jenkins and Artifactory Pro and can successfully build my project and deploy it's artifacts to Artifactory. I have also written a bash script to retrieve the resulting artifacts of a specific build from Artifactory and copy them somewhere.

The main part I'm missing right now is automated versioning. I've looked at enabling Artifactory release management, which is really cool, but involves the rebuilding of the project. I'm really trying to follow the mantra of 'Build Once, Deploy Anywhere', so any rebuilding is a no-no.

My question boils down to: Is there an automated way (either with one of the aforementioned tools, or a plugin) to handle versioning, without rebuilding an artifact?

Comment: have you looked into the maven release plugin with jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory Pro allows you to easily extend Artifactory's behavior with your own plugins written in groovy. (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins)

You can find [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/build/promotion.groovy), an example of Promote extension, that will change your artifacts versions without the needs of new build.

You can find more usefully examples in the GitHub "artifactory-user-plugins" repository.